# Postgres 10 TDS_FDW extension undefined symbol: Float4GetDatum

Tags: postgresql, tds-fdw

I'm trying to add the tds fdw extension to a new installation of Postgres 10 on CentOS.
I've run make/install for the tds_fdw, but when attempting to

```
CREATE EXTENSION tds_fdw;
```

from PG Admin it fails with the message:

```
ERROR: could not load library "/usr/pgsql-10/lib/tds_fdw.so": /usr/pgsql-10/lib/tds_fdw.so: undefined symbol: Float4GetDatum
SQL state: XX000
```

I'm new to CentOS and building anything postgres related. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the PostgreSQL for which you built the extension is configured in a different way than the one where you try to run it.

The obvious cause would be if the one for which you built tds_fdw was configured with `--disable-float4-byval`.

Comment: Looks like I had the wrong version my build command on one pass. Once I changed the build command (sudo PATH=/usr/pgsql-10/bin:$PATH make USE_PGXS=1) rather than 9.3, it worked. Thanks!